# How to Open a Share path File Location in Ext JS Grid column

Tags: javascript, extjs

How to Open a file From EXt JS Grid column.

file locn ex:

\Computername\dir\folder\file.csv

Grid Renderer  only opens a hyper link and not Share paths

Thanks in Advance for ur answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way. Windows shared file paths are not standard conforming pathes.

You can add the path as a drive in Windows explorer:

- Browse to "This PC".
- From network tab, use "Connect network drive".
- Browse to network location
- Select the drive's character (e.g. `Y:`).

Afterwards you can use the `file://` pattern for local file access: `url:'file://Y:/path/to/file.csv'`.